# JSON vs const object for image gallery web app (React Native)

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, react-native, image

Hello I'm trying to build an image gallery as practice and for my portfolio using React Native and expo router. I'm using the below code in a .js file to store the details of the artwork. But what are the advantage of using this `export const` vs storing it in a .json file?

```
export const artwork = [
    {   
        id: '1',
        source: require('../assets/images/art/Charizard.jpg'),
        artist: 'Antonio Banderas',
        title: 'Charizard Gigantimax',
        about: 'This is a shiny Charizard that has gigantimaxed in Galar.' 
    }
]
```

Below is the same code in a json file. Please feel free to point out anything I'm doing wrong.

```
[
    {   
        "id": "1",
        "source": "../assets/images/art/Charizard.jpg",
        "artist": "Antonio Banderas",
        "title": "Charizard Gigantimax",
        "about": "This is a shiny Charizard that has gigantimaxed in Galar." 
    }
]
```

It might be too much for one post but I'm wondering, *is it best practice to bundle the images with the website files or upload them to a database for this use?*

Thank you **so much** for your help in advance.

Here is the [Charizard](https://tcg.pokemon.com/en-gb/wallpapers/) in case you were curious. :) You'll have to scroll down a bit.

Answer (score 0):

yes it's the best way. require mean it's will run on compile app, this create reference to assets item, and does not took any performance.